# ubuntu 18,04 stuck in read only mode and fsck doesn't fix it

Tags: 18.04

hello last night my PC got DC'd from the power source and shut down suddenly as far as im aware it wasnt performing any updates or such, it refused to get past loading screen and wouldn't access ttyl, used a live USB to manually sudo fsck -f to fix the issues and it still wouldnt boot past loading screen or get to ttyl.

i can access grub screen and recovery i used systemd.unit=multi-user.target 
and it allowed me to access ttyl from there i tried to perform fsck and update but it wouldnt allow me to do anything because it says its in read only mode, tried to mount it to rw but its write protected 
same thing with recovery mode basically, recovery menu says its read/write however when i attempt to repair broken packages or anything it gives me read only errors

please help me get to the root of the issue using. dmesg in recovery mode gives me

```
[937256380] sd 0:0:0:0: (sda) tag#10 CDB: Read (10)28003869 1800000080
00

[937256381 ] print_req_error: 1/0 error, dev sda, sector 951711832
[937256417] ata1: EH complete
[940985080] ata1.00: exception Emask OxO SACE 0x200 SErr Ox0 action oxo
[940985083] ata1.00: Irg.stat 0x40000008
[940985087] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[940985103] ata1.00: cmd 60/80:48:00:f8:b9/00:00:38:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 65
536 in

res 41/40:80:58:f8:b9/00:00:38:00:00/40 Emask Ox409 (med

la error) <F>
[940985104] ata1.00: status: ( DRDY ERR )
[940985105] ata1.00: error: { UNC )
[940988344] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 940988357] sd 0:0:0:0: (sda) tag 19 FAILED Result: hostbyte:DID_OK driverbyte
=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 940988360 ] sd 0:0:0:0: (sdal tag 9 Sense Key : Medium Error (current)
[ 940988362] sd 0:0:0:0: (sda) tag 9 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto
reallocate falled
[940988365] sd 0:0:0:0: (sda) taga9 CDB: Read 10280038 b9 f8 00 00 00 80

00
[ 940988366]print_req_error: I/0 error, dev sda, sector 951711832
[940988403] ata1: EH complete
```

my laptop runs on radeon graphics and Intel i7 cpu

edit #1 : pictures of the drive's smart data https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJZMp.jpg

edit #2: after booting to my live usb and taking a picture of the drive's smart data, i preformed a manual fsck on said drive and shut down, then i proceeded to follow @heynnema 's instructions and disabled ncq which solved my problem permenantly :)

Comment: Your HDD may be failing, or you may have a NCQ error situation. Do this... boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start the `Disks` app, select SMART Data from the "hamburger" menu, take screenshot(s), and update your question, or post them to imgur.com and give me the URL. Do you have good backups? We **may** run a bad block test on the HDD (you don't have an SSD, correct?). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema
https://imgur.com/a/GN5myU9 
i have only the files backed up no actual save point for the drive but i dont much care for any settings and such.
and yes its an hdd

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes to write a partial answer for you. Report back after you do the instructions.

Comment: Did you complete a `fsck` on the drive?

Comment: @heynnema yes i did a fsck from live USB before shutting down just in case

Comment: You had to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to `fsck`, yes?

Comment: @heynnema yes because recovery mode hits me with read only errors and ttyl doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hard disk may be failing. You may have one of two possible problems with your HDD. Lets try and eliminate the easiest one first.

**NCQ errors...**

- turn on the computer
- get to the GRUB menu
- assure that the desired boot choice is highlighted
- hit the <kbd>e</kbd> to enter edit mode
- use the arrow keys to find the string "quiet splash"
- change that to "quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
- hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting
- see if things are improved

**Bad blocking the HDD...**

- Pending

**Update #1:**

To make the temporary NCQ tweak permanent...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Find "quiet splash"

Change it to "quiet splash libata.force=noncq"

Save the file.

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

In the SMART Data, keep an eye on "Current Pending Sector Count" and assure that it doesn't increase. If it does, then we WILL have to bad block the HDD.

Comment: it worked!! i booted into log in and logged in no problems!!!

Comment: @Allakh let me update my answer with how to make that permanent.

Comment: i did as told and made it permanent, reboot was successful and no change in the current pending sector count still resting at 3896

Comment: thank you so much for your quick help i appreciate it a lot